# Redirect requests to my external IP/port to an internal IP/port?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I have a dedicated server running KVM virtualization with n public IP addresses dedicated to n-1 web-facing virtual machines. Now I'd like to set up some web-facing VM's that don't have a dedicated address, but instead will have 2 or 3 ports forwarded for them from the host machine.

Bridge configuration is:

```
brctl show
```

[image]

Let's say I would like to forward

- 178.126.193.153:201 to 192.168.1.101:22
- 178.126.193.153:801 to 192.168.1.101:80

First, I have enabled port forwarding on a host machine by uncommenting

```
# net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, then I did

```
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
service network restart
```

Then, similar to the recipe in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/28516/181242), I did:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i br0 --dport 201 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.101:22
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.1.101 --dport 201 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i br0 --dport 801 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.101:80
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.1.101 --dport 801 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

I ran `ifconfig` on a guest machine and checked that its interface eth0, indeed, has the IP address 192.168.1.101. The interface inside of virtual machine is called `eth0`, is this right?

But it doesn't work:

`nmap 178.126.193.153` doesn't show an open port 201 nor 801, and `ssh -l root -p 201 178.126.193.153` gets me

```
ssh: connect to host 178.126.193.153 port 201: Connection refused
```

`ip route` on a host machine returns

```
178.126.193.128/26 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 178.162.193.153 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.1 
169.254.0.0/16 dev br0  scope link  metric 1004 
default via 178.126.193.190 dev br0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you enable forwarding? `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 net.ipv4.conf.br0.forwarding=1 net.ipv4.conf.virbr0.forwarding=1`

Comment: @Patrick Ack! I thought I did, but I actually didn't! Now, I made sure I did, but the problem persists. I have revised my question.

Comment: @Patrick I think I'm not getting exactly when, if at all, I should be using `virbr0-nic` instead of `eth0`?

Answer (score 3):

When you forward traffic to a different prot you need to add postrouting SNAT rule (or masquerade, it doesn't matter). Also you made some mistakes at forward rule. So try this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i br0 --dport 201 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.101:22
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.1.101 --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.1.101 -p tcp --dport 22 -j SNAT --to-source 178.126.193.153
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable loopback routing. I did this on my router with the following:

`iptables -A FORWARD -o eth1 -d $IP -j ACCEPT`

`iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

In my setup, eth0 is the internet interface, $IP is the internet IP, and eth1 is the internal interface.

The key here is that you need a FORWARD rule for traffic going out your internal interface with the external destination IP. It's a bit confusing logically because this rule is applied before the DNAT.

The second rule just accepts internal traffic to be forwarded in the first place, you can achieve this in different ways.

I'm not sure if additional special things apply here due to the virtual networking portion, you might need ebtables to make it work too.

Comment: Do I have to do this on the host machine (I'm providing internet connection to VM's here), in addition to the rules I have set up in my question? I fail to see which does what. I wonder what would eth0 and eth1 be, on my system: I guess, `eth0` and `virbr0-nic`?

Comment: It would be on whichever machine is holding your external IP, whether that's a VM or the host. If it's a VM, the routing will probably be a little different, but similar.